# openvpn client not getting dhcp IP from lan

Tags: vpn, openvpn, amazon-vpc

i have configured openvpn in  bridged mode using openvpn AS. when i connect with server, the client does not get any IP address from the LAN of the network of openvpn AS server.

This is what i get in logs

```
2017-09-20 11:55:21+0000 [-] OVPN 1 OUT: 'Wed Sep 20 11:55:21 2017
58.65.47.21:58444 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]58.65.47.21:58444, sid=1742aa0c 97b95f66' 2017-09-20 11:55:22+0000 [-] OVPN 1 OUT: 'Wed Sep 20 11:55:22 2017 58.65.47.21:58444 VERIFY OK: depth=1, /CN=OpenVPN CA' 2017-09-20 11:55:22+0000 [-] OVPN 1 OUT: 'Wed Sep 20 11:55:22 2017
58.65.47.21:58444 VERIFY OK: nsCertType=CLIENT' 2017-09-20 11:55:22+0000 [-] OVPN 1 OUT: 'Wed Sep 20 11:55:22 2017
58.65.47.21:58444 VERIFY OK: depth=0, /CN=openvpn_AUTOLOGIN' 2017-09-20 11:55:22+0000 [-] OVPN 1 OUT: 'Wed Sep 20 11:55:22 2017
58.65.47.21:58444 WARNING: INSECURE cipher with block size less than 128 bit (64 bit).  This allows attacks like SWEET32.  Mitigate by using a --cipher with a larger block size (e.g. AES-256-CBC).' 2017-09-20 11:55:22+0000 [-] OVPN 1 OUT: 'Wed Sep 20 11:55:22 2017
58.65.47.21:58444 WARNING: INSECURE cipher with block size less than 128 bit (64 bit).  This allows attacks like SWEET32.  Mitigate by using a --cipher with a larger block size (e.g. AES-256-CBC).' 2017-09-20 11:55:22+0000 [-] OVPN 1 OUT: 'Wed Sep 20 11:55:22 2017
58.65.47.21:58444 WARNING: cipher with small block size in use, reducing reneg-bytes to 64MB to mitigate SWEET32 attacks.' 2017-09-20 11:55:22+0000 [-] AUTH SUCCESS {'status': 0, 'reason': 'AuthTrue: autologin certificate auth succeeded', 'serial_list': [], 'user': u'openvpn', 'proplist': {u'pvt_google_auth_secret_locked': u'false', u'prop_autogenerate': u'true', u'type': u'user_compile', u'pvt_google_auth_secret': '[redacted]', u'prop_autologin': u'true', u'prop_superuser': u'true'}, 'common_name': u'openvpn_AUTOLOGIN', 'serial': '6'} cli=u'win'/u'3.1.1' 2017-09-20 11:55:22+0000 [-] OVPN 1 OUT: "Wed Sep 20 11:55:22 2017 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'client-auth 2 0'" 2017-09-20 11:55:22+0000 [-] OVPN 1 OUT: 'Wed Sep 20 11:55:22 2017
58.65.47.21:58444 Control Channel: TLSv1.2, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, 2048 bit RSA' 2017-09-20 11:55:22+0000 [-] OVPN 1 OUT: 'Wed Sep 20 11:55:22 2017 58.65.47.21:58444 [openvpn_AUTOLOGIN] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]58.65.47.21:58444' 2017-09-20 11:55:22+0000 [-] OVPN 1 OUT: 'Wed Sep 20 11:55:22 2017 openvpn_AUTOLOGIN/58.65.47.21:58444 OPTIONS IMPORT: LZO parms modified' 2017-09-20 11:55:22+0000 [-] OVPN 1 OUT: 'Wed Sep 20 11:55:22 2017 openvpn_AUTOLOGIN/58.65.47.21:58444 MULTI: no dynamic or static remote --ifconfig address is available for openvpn_AUTOLOGIN/58.65.47.21:58444' 2017-09-20 11:55:22+0000 [-] OVPN 1 OUT: 'Wed Sep 20 11:55:22 2017 openvpn_AUTOLOGIN/58.65.47.21:58444 send_push_reply(): safe_cap=940' 2017-09-20 11:55:22+0000 [-] OVPN 1 OUT: "Wed Sep 20 11:55:22 2017 openvpn_AUTOLOGIN/58.65.47.21:58444 SENT CONTROL [openvpn_AUTOLOGIN]: 'PUSH_REPLY,explicit-exit-notify,route-gateway dhcp,route-delay 5 30,dhcp-pre-release,dhcp-renew,dhcp-release,route-metric 101,ping 12,ping-restart 50,comp-lzo yes,redirect-gateway def1,redirect-gateway bypass-dhcp,redirect-gateway autolocal,block-ipv6' (status=1)" 2017-09-20 11:55:25+0000 [-] OVPN 1 OUT: 'Wed Sep 20 11:55:25 2017
58.65.47.21:41882 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]58.65.47.21:41882, sid=0e044e85 9aac96fb' 2017-09-20 11:55:25+0000 [-] OVPN 1 OUT: 'Wed Sep 20 11:55:25 2017 58.65.47.21:41882 VERIFY OK: depth=1, /CN=OpenVPN CA' 2017-09-20 11:55:25+0000 [-] OVPN 1 OUT: 'Wed Sep 20 11:55:25 2017
58.65.47.21:41882 VERIFY OK: nsCertType=CLIENT' 2017-09-20 11:55:25+0000 [-] OVPN 1 OUT: 'Wed Sep 20 11:55:25 2017
58.65.47.21:41882 VERIFY OK: depth=0, /CN=openvpn_AUTOLOGIN' 2017-09-20 11:55:26+0000 [-] OVPN 1 OUT: 'Wed Sep 20 11:55:26 2017
58.65.47.21:41882 WARNING: INSECURE cipher with block size less than 128 bit (64 bit).  This allows attacks like SWEET32.  Mitigate by using a --cipher with a larger block size (e.g. AES-256-CBC).' 2017-09-20 11:55:26+0000 [-] OVPN 1 OUT: 'Wed Sep 20 11:55:26 2017
58.65.47.21:41882 WARNING: INSECURE cipher with block size less than 128 bit (64 bit).  This allows attacks like SWEET32.  Mitigate by using a --cipher with a larger block size (e.g. AES-256-CBC).' 2017-09-20 11:55:26+0000 [-] OVPN 1 OUT: 'Wed Sep 20 11:55:26 2017
58.65.47.21:41882 WARNING: cipher with small block size in use, reducing reneg-bytes to 64MB to mitigate SWEET32 attacks.' 2017-09-20 11:55:26+0000 [OMIClientAuth,0,] AUTH SUCCESS {'status': 0, 'reason': 'AuthTrue: autologin certificate auth succeeded', 'serial_list': [], 'user': u'openvpn', 'proplist': {u'pvt_google_auth_secret_locked': u'false', u'prop_autogenerate': u'true', u'type': u'user_compile', u'pvt_google_auth_secret': '[redacted]', u'prop_autologin': u'true', u'prop_superuser': u'true'}, 'common_name': u'openvpn_AUTOLOGIN', 'serial': '6'} cli=u'win'/u'3.1.1' 2017-09-20 11:55:26+0000 [-] OVPN 1 OUT: 'Wed Sep 20 11:55:26 2017 MANAGEMENT: CMD \'client-kill 2 "HALT,disconnected due to new connection by same user"\'' 2017-09-20 11:55:26+0000 [-] OVPN 1 OUT: 'Wed Sep 20 11:55:26 2017 Delayed exit in 5 seconds' 2017-09-20 11:55:26+0000 [-] OVPN 1 OUT: "Wed Sep 20 11:55:26 2017 SENT CONTROL [openvpn_AUTOLOGIN]: 'HALT,disconnected due to new connection by same user' (status=1)" 2017-09-20 11:55:26+0000 [-] OVPN 1 OUT: "Wed Sep 20 11:55:26 2017 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'client-auth 3 0'" 2017-09-20 11:55:26+0000 [-] OVPN 1 OUT: 'Wed Sep 20 11:55:26 2017 58.65.47.21:41882 Control Channel: TLSv1.2, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, 2048 bit RSA' 2017-09-20 11:55:26+0000 [-] OVPN 1 OUT: 'Wed Sep 20 11:55:26 2017 58.65.47.21:41882 [openvpn_AUTOLOGIN] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]58.65.47.21:41882' 2017-09-20 11:55:26+0000 [-] OVPN 1 OUT: 'Wed Sep 20 11:55:26 2017 openvpn_AUTOLOGIN/58.65.47.21:41882 OPTIONS IMPORT: LZO parms modified' 2017-09-20 11:55:26+0000 [-] OVPN 1 OUT: 'Wed Sep 20 11:55:26 2017 openvpn_AUTOLOGIN/58.65.47.21:41882 MULTI: no dynamic or static remote --ifconfig address is available for openvpn_AUTOLOGIN/58.65.47.21:41882' 2017-09-20 11:55:26+0000 [-] OVPN 1 OUT: 'Wed Sep 20 11:55:26 2017 openvpn_AUTOLOGIN/58.65.47.21:41882 send_push_reply(): safe_cap=940' 2017-09-20 11:55:26+0000 [-] OVPN 1 OUT: "Wed Sep 20 11:55:26 2017 openvpn_AUTOLOGIN/58.65.47.21:41882 SENT CONTROL [openvpn_AUTOLOGIN]: 'PUSH_REPLY,explicit-exit-notify,route-gateway dhcp,route-delay 5 30,dhcp-pre-release,dhcp-renew,dhcp-release,route-metric 101,ping 12,ping-restart 50,comp-lzo yes,redirect-gateway def1,redirect-gateway bypass-dhcp,redirect-gateway autolocal,block-ipv6' (status=1)" 2017-09-20 11:55:26+0000 [-] OVPN 1 OUT: 'Wed Sep 20 11:55:26 2017 openvpn_AUTOLOGIN/58.65.47.21:41882 MULTI: Learn: 00:ff:25:0a:6e:5b -> openvpn_AUTOLOGIN/58.65.47.21:41882' 2017-09-20 11:55:31+0000 [-] OVPN 1 OUT: 'Wed Sep 20 11:55:31 2017 openvpn_AUTOLOGIN/58.65.47.21:58444 SIGTERM[soft,delayed-exit] received, client-instance exiting'
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible to see anything related to this in the OpenVPN logs. You have to run `tcpdump` looking for DHCP traffic, on both ends.

Comment: If this server is inside a VM, you have to make sure your hypervisor allows foreign MAC addresses, in VMWare this is accomplished by setting "Forged Transmits" and "Promiscuous mode" to Accept. Otherwise your bridge would populate MACs, but won't be able to forward traffic.

Comment: its an EC2 server in AWS

Comment: Amazon VPC network is not true L2-domain environment, it's only emulating certain features, so bridging with it won't work as expected. You need to set up a separate network and route your traffic instead of bridging.